# Retrieve bean from external package configuration class in a ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to retrieve a bean that is defined in a different package in a `ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar`.

So for example, the bean in the different package is defined as:

```
package com.differentpackage

@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "app.some-property", havingValue = "true")
public class ExternalConfiguration {
    private ExampleProperties exampleProperties;

    public ExternalConfiguration(ExampleProperties exampleProperties) {
        this.exampleProperties = exampleProperties;
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "destroy")
    public ExampleBean exampleBean()  {
        return new ExampleBean();
    }

    // other beans
    // ...
}
```

I want to get ahold of `ExampleBean` in my `ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar`:

```
package com.example

class MyRegistrar implements ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar {
    @Override
    public void registerBeanDefinitions(AnnotationMetadata metadata, BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {
        // Will result in a NoSuchBeanDefinitionException exception.
        ExampleBean exampleBean = ((DefaultListableBeanFactory) registry).getBean(ExampleBean.class);
    }
}
```

How would I go about retrieving that bean in my registrar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring by default only scan from the package and all of the sub-packages that `@SpringBootApplication` is located . You can configure `scanBasePackages` in `@SpringBootConfiguration` to change the scanning packages :

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages= {"com.differentpackage" ,"com.example" })
```

Also , make sure that the `application.properties` really defines `app.some-property=true` such that `ExternalConfiguration` are enabled.